# SizzlingKeys (Music / iTunes Key Control) replacement for macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, itunes, macos-catalina

I'm in love with [SizzlingKeys](http://www.yellowmug.com/sk4it/). It has been the best tool for iTunes for me for the past decade and I just can't live without it. :'(

It allows me to do everything I want to do with my music with a few quick key presses.  For example, I can play/pause with cmd-opt-spacebar. I can rank my music with stars via option-cmd-num#0-5. Everything is so quick and smooth.

Is there anything that can compare with this for Catalina now that Apple has decided to be so cruel by tearing out 32bit support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfred 4 fits this niche nearly perfectly.

Go to `Alfred Preferences` -> `Workflows` -> `+`. Then click `Templates` -> `iTunes` and pick the function you want to set up with its accompanying keyboard shortcut.

[image: screenshot]

NOTE: Alfred is still using "iTunes" instead of "Music" in version 4.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I know I, like several Mac users, have enjoyed the benefits of SizzlingKeys key commands to Play/Pause iTunes without having to look down at my keyboard to find the F8 key.  Now with moving onto Mac OS X Catalina 10.15 and the death of iTunes on the Mac, now rebranded the 'Music' application, using SizzlingKeys is no longer an option. After endless Googling on the web, I've found a solution that works well for me as my SizzlingKeys replacement. I've been using '[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/#Overview)' application. It allows me to add a Global Macro that easily let me assign Option-Command-Spacebar to be my toggle for Play/Pause of the 'Music' app while I'm surfing the web or active in any other application and I don't have to look down at my keyboard for finding the F8 key or even think about it if I need to quickly pause a track from playing.

Comment: Have you been able to get skip and rating to work on `Keyboard Maestro` yet? I've had problems there in the past and gave up on it. `Alfred` has been doing better in this regard for me...

Comment: I believe there are options to create keyboard shortcuts for both Skip and Rating based on what's built into Keyboard Maestro already. I've only applied key commands to the 'Play/Pause Current Track,' 'Next Track,' and 'Previous Track' options.